# Scroll content of ionic slides independently

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Is there a way to scroll content of every ion-slide idependently from other slides?

In later versions there was a "workaround" using ion-scroll which is deprecated now. So every slide "caches" their latest scroll position.

```
<ion-slide>
   <ion-scroll>
      ... my content
   </ion-scroll>
</ion-slide>
```

Comment: Please check [this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/dynamic-slide-height/63891/16) from Ionic forum.

Comment: Can't find a solution there. I can scroll my slides...but when I change then I will scroll to the last position...so i need scroll for every slide and not only the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use `[options]` in `ion-slides`, maybe that's what you need.

example:

> <ion-slides [options]="{ autoHeight: true }">